# Sencha Touch 2.3.1 NestedList works in browser; not on ipad compile

Tags: ipad, extjs, sencha-touch, nested-lists

Has anyone ever experianced trouble where a sencha touch (2.3.1) nested list works on a browser (safari and chrome) but doesn't respond to tap events on the actual ipad?

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your browser console shows any [DEPRECATED] message. If you compile a working uncompiled ST app that uses [DEPRECATED] functions, the compiled version won't work.

Comment: I'm still having this problem.  The only [DEPRECATED] messaged I was receiving was that the cls was on the item directly and should have been in a config.  That is fixed, but the nested list still does not respond to touch events(including scroll).  Any other ideas?